# Nicer <kbd> style

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, formatting, css

Apple.SE has a much nicer design for <kbd>kbd</kbd> tags:

[image]

It works much better for embedding it in other text (e.g. an explanation) as it contains a sans-serif font and a more subtle border. The style currently used on Super User disrupts the text flow and makes reading explanations that contain embedded <kbd>kbd formatted keys</kbd> more difficult. For example from [here](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/1042):

> [image]

It also uses a real font, instead of the browser's default. `kbd` is probably the only part of SU that uses the default font, given how often a sequence of preferred monospaced fonts is declared in the CSS file.

---

Please change the style for `kbd` tags used on SU and MSU to something similar to the style used on Apple.SE to improve legibility of posts that use this formatting.

Comment: I'm very much for this.

Comment: For this topic, a separate answer to vote for doesn't make sense IMO. Please **agree** with my request by up voting, **disagree** by down voting.

Comment: @DanielBeck Yup, it's always been like that for `feature-request`s on all Metas, it wouldn't make sense to answer it.

Comment: Here, here! The formatting of the `<kbd>` tag has always seemed rather atrocious.

Comment: [Amusing post on meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974) about the same topic =)

Comment: @nhinkle Any idea how we can actually make this happen? Votes look pretty good so far.

Comment: @DanielBeck I can ask a dev to look into it.

Comment: @nhinkle Could you get confirmation that they can do this, and once confirmed, we'll give it another two days or so for counterarguments to come up, then we'll see what the score is?

Comment: @DanielBeck I can assure you that it would be _possible_ to change, but I don't know if they'll want to invest the time. I assume it wouldn't be too hard. If you want to wait for counterarguments, let's just wait another couple days and I'll bring it to them then.

Comment: Not really a counter-argument, but I don't think that we should have the same `<kbd>` style as Apple.SE as we deal with more than apple products. Perhaps potential styles could be answers?

Comment: @soandos we have the same kbd style as stack overflow, but don't deal with programming either... It doesn't need to be identical, but the fact remains the current style is horrible to read. If You find a better one than apple.se, present it here, and we can take a vote which style is the du communitys favourite.

Comment: @DanielBeck I passed this along to the team. They sent a message to Jin (the designer for SE) to take a look at it.

Comment: I plan to make some tweaks to the KBD styling for the Trilogy site. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 14):

The keyboard on Apple.SE also looks much better than the [one on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1950/151367):

[image]

Comment: Haha... it even looks better than [10.6's Keyboard Viewer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8XS7w.png).